# Why the same data is printed differently when built with list or cons?

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I tried to reproduce the same data layout by using different combinations of `list` and `cons`. In MIT Scheme, the same data layout seems to be printed differently depending on how it was built.

In example,

```
> (cons 1 (cons 2 3))
(1 2 . 3)
> (list 1 (cons 2 3))
(1 (2 . 3))
> (cons 1 (list 2 3))
(1 2 3)
> (list 1 (list 2 3))
(1 (2 3))
```

The underlying data should always be the same. Why does MIT Scheme represents it differently? Is the underlying arrangements of pairs really the same every time?

Comment: `(list 1 2 3)` is equivalent of `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`.

Comment: The objects are different, please try `equal` to see for yourself. You might find the page [Dotted-Pair-Notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html) useful.

Comment: If `(cons 1 (cons 2 3))` returned the same thing as `(list 1 (list 2 3))`, that would make `cons` and `list` synonyms (in the two-argument cases, at least); they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the inputs is building a different output, so they're printed differently. Notice that the following expressions are equivalent:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 3))
; (1 2 . 3)

(list 1 (cons 2 3))
(cons 1 (cons (cons 2 3) '()))
; (1 (2 . 3))

(cons 1 (list 2 3))
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
; (1 2 3)

(list 1 (list 2 3))
(cons 1 (cons (cons 2 (cons 3 '())) '()))
; (1 (2 3))
```

Remember: a list is defined if and only if the `cdr` part of each `cons` is also a `cons` cell, or an empty list.